# Исключение элементов из массивов с помощью поэлементного сравнивания (numpy)

Tags: python, массивы, numpy, matplotlib

Я только начал изучать python. А именно начал с изображения аналитических функций с помощью mathplotlib и математических вычислений с помощью numpy. [image: Окружность с разрывом]
В попытках изобразить прерывную окружность, столкнулся с проблемой, что из канонического уравнения окружности не могу исключить некоторое множество точек. Попытался через np.where, но не понял сути.

```
r = 4
x = np.linspace(-r,r,100)
y = np.sqrt(-x**2+r**2)
np.where((y < 1.5*x or (y < -2.2*x,x,y))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x,-y)
```

Вопрос: Каким образом из массива Y исключить точки, которые не входят в область  y < -2.2x && y < 1.5x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- используйте **побитовые** операции над условиями, а не **логические**, т.е. `&` и `|`, а не `and` и `or`
- используйте в `np.where` значение `np.nan`, чтобы пометить не нужные элементы
- используйте маску, чтобы удалить из массива не нужные элементы

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np

r = 4
x = np.linspace(-r,r,100)
y = np.sqrt(-x**2+r**2)
index = np.where((y < 1.5*x) | (y < -2.2*x),x,np.nan)
x1 = np.ma.array(x, mask=np.isnan(index))
y1 = np.ma.array(y, mask=np.isnan(index))
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.plot(x,-y)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое! Полностью исчерпывающий ответ